# Vagrant VM does not boot up properly

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I am trying to get up my vagrant up, but am having some trouble with it. This is what happens when I do a vagrant up

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/centos65-x64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'puphpet/centos65-x64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20161004'. The latest is version '20161102'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 (guest) => 9090 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8443 (guest) => 9443 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8787 (guest) => 8787 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3307 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9990 (guest) => 9990 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

When I do a vagrant ssh-config, I get the following

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "/Users/ritwickgupta/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

I tried looking what was happening in my VM, and everything looks ok. I can login into my VM without any issue. Does anyone what what's happening here?

[image: VM Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built the box version you are currently using, `20161004`, with VirtualBox 5.1.x. This required users to upgrade to that version for boxes to work.

I have since rebuilt the boxes using VirtualBox 5.0.16, `20161102`.

Please delete your local box and download the new version.